# How do I aggregate a 2D tensor while some of them have to be averaged and some of them retained?

Tags: python, pytorch, aggregate, tensor

I want to aggregate a 2D tensor. The rule is, if the number in the the variable "idx" is the same, average the corresponding tensor. Below is the problem.

```
idx = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])
x = torch.tensor([[10, 10, 10], [11, 11, 11], [12, 12, 12],
                  [13, 13, 13], [14, 14, 14], [15, 15, 15],
                  [16, 16, 16], [17, 17, 17], [18, 18, 18]])
```

For example, since index (1, 2) is repeated, the corresponding tensors

```
[[11, 11, 11], [12, 12, 12]] and [[13, 13, 13], [14, 14, 14]]
```

will be aggregated and thus we get the tensor

```
[[12, 12, 12], [13, 13, 13]]
```

if there is no repeated number, keep the tensor. So for this problem the desired answer is

```
torch.tensor([[10, 10, 10], [12, 12, 12], [13, 13, 13], [15.5, 15.5, 15.5], [17, 17, 17], [18, 18, 18]])
```

How do I do this? Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: Can you have more than two occurrence of the same index? Also are the triplets always equal?

Comment: No, the same index will have two occurences at most, and the triplets are not always equal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use a scatter function.

##### Minimal setup in 2D

Let us explore a reduced version of your problem whereby instead of having triplets, we have single values. In that scenario, we would have:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[10, 11, 12],
                      [13, 14, 15],
                      [16, 17, 18]])

>>> idx = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2],
                        [1, 2, 3],
                        [3, 4, 5]])
```

We should look at an intermediate result rather than the desired result itself. Ultimately, we know that the result will be summed or averaged along one of its dimensions. We can first define its shape, it should have as many rows as `x` and `idx` and as many columns as there are unique indices in `idx`. In this particular example, the intermediate result we're looking for will have a shape of `(3, 6)`. Since `#[|0,5|]=6`:

```
tensor([[10, 11, 12,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 13, 14, 15,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0, 16, 17, 18]])
```

We can see that once reduced along the first dimension, we get:

```
tensor([10., 12., 13., 15.5, 17., 18.])
```

Which is the desired result for this minimal example in 1D.

To do such operation we can benefit from [`torch.Tensor.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_). When applied on two-dimensional tensors, and setting `dim=1`, calling this line:

```
out.scatter_(dim=1, index=idx, src=x)
```

will have the following effect on `out`:

```
out[i][idx[i][j]] = x[i][j]
```

If we try on our input tensors, we get:

```
>>> o = torch.zeros(len(idx), idx.max()+1, dtype=int)
>>> o.scatter_(1, idx, x)
tensor([[10, 11, 12,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 13, 14, 15,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0, 16, 17, 18]])
```

Then we only have to average over nonzero values using [`torch.sum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sum.html) and [`torch.count_nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.count_nonzero.html):

```
>>> o.sum(dim=0) / o.count_nonzero(dim=0)
tensor([10.0000, 12.0000, 13.0000, 15.5000, 17.0000, 18.0000])
```

---

##### Original problem

However, in your original use case, you have three values per element:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[10, 10, 10], [11, 11, 11], [12, 12, 12],
                      [13, 13, 13], [14, 14, 14], [15, 15, 15],
                      [16, 16, 16], [17, 17, 17], [18, 18, 18]])

>>> idx = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2], 
                        [1, 2, 3], 
                        [3, 4, 5]])
```

Therefore, we first have to do the following on `x` and `idx`:

1. reshape `x` to a 3D tensor with shape `(*idx.shape, x.size(-1))`:

   ```
   >>> x_ = x.view(*idx.shape, x.size(-1))
   tensor([[[10, 10, 10],
            [11, 11, 11],
            [12, 12, 12]],

           [[13, 13, 13],
            [14, 14, 14],
            [15, 15, 15]],

           [[16, 16, 16],
            [17, 17, 17],
            [18, 18, 18]]])
   ```
2. Unsqueeze and expand `idx` such that it has the same shape as `x_`:

   ```
   >>> idx_ = idx.unsqueeze(-1).expand_as(x_)
   tensor([[[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2]],

           [[1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [3, 3, 3]],

           [[3, 3, 3],
            [4, 4, 4],
            [5, 5, 5]]])
   ```

Then we simply have to apply the same approach with `torch.scatter`, but in 3D, *i.e.* `out.scatter_(dim=1, index=idx_, src=x_)` which will result in:

```
out[i][idx[i][j][k]][k] = x[i][j][k]
```

For our inputs:

```
>>> o = torch.zeros(len(idx), idx.max()+1, idx.size(-1), dtype=int)
>>> o.scatter_(1, idx_, x_)
tensor([[[10, 10, 10],
         [11, 11, 11],
         [12, 12, 12],
         [ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0,  0],
         [13, 13, 13],
         [14, 14, 14],
         [15, 15, 15],
         [ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0],
         [16, 16, 16],
         [17, 17, 17],
         [18, 18, 18]]])
```

To finish it off, reduce on `dim=1`, same way as before:

```
>>> o.sum(dim=0) / o.count_nonzero(dim=0)
tensor([[10.0000, 10.0000, 10.0000],
        [12.0000, 12.0000, 12.0000],
        [13.0000, 13.0000, 13.0000],
        [15.5000, 15.5000, 15.5000],
        [17.0000, 17.0000, 17.0000],
        [18.0000, 18.0000, 18.0000]])
```